# How can I pass variable instead table name in @Query annotation in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to pass variable instead table name using @Query annotation but doesn't work..

```
@Modifying
 @Query(value="insert into :table (name,password) values (:name,:password)",nativeQuery=true) 
 void add  (@Param(":table") String table,@Param("name") String name,@Param("password") String password);
```

> please, I want to pass variable instead table name what ever the way is.

Comment: Looks like you have typo `@Param(":table")`, it should be `@Param("table")`

Comment: I changed it and also not working

Comment: You can try this: `"insert into " + table + " (name...`. Also, remove `@Param` for table

Comment: and how can i pass dynamic variable from out side the interface ?